# Ordered Fields, Infinitely large and small elements, Example

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

In Section XI of *Algebra* by Serge Lang, he introduces ordered fields. On the second page he gives the following example.

> *Example*: We define an ordering on the polynomial ring $\mathbb{R}[t]$ over the real numbers. A polynomial
>   $$
>  f(t) = a_n t^n + \ldots + a_0
> $$
>   with $a_n \ne 0$ is defined to be positive if $a_n > 0$. The two axioms are then trivially verified. We note that $t > a$ for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$. Thus $t$ is infinitely large with respect to $\mathbb{R}$. The existence of inifinitely large (or infinitely small) elements in an ordered field is the main aspect in which such a field differs from a subfield of the real numbers.

Why does it follow that $t > a$ for all $a \in R$? I can't even comprehend this statement because $t$ is a variable, and as such could attend values for which $t < a$?

Comment: $t$ is not a variable. It is a polynomial. Lang has just defined an order on polynomials. Do you not understand the definition?

Comment: ah, yes okay now it makes sense, too easy... mhh cannot accept your comment as an answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $t$ here means the polynomial $t$, or the $f(t)$ where $a_1=1$ and $\forall i\neq 1,a_i=0$.

Answer (score 1):

By definition we have $\rm\:  f > g \iff f-g > 0,\:$ i.e. $\rm\:f - g \:$ has positive leading coefficient. Therefore $\rm\: t > a\:$ since $\rm\: t-a\:$ has leading coefficient $\rm\: 1 > 0.\:$

The idea behind this ordering is that $\rm\: f > g\:$ iff this eventually holds true for large values of $\rm\:t,\:$ i.e. in a neighborhood of $\rm\,+\infty.\:$ Since the leading term eventually dominates all other terms as $\rm\:t\to +\infty,\:$ it determines the sign of $\rm\,f\,$ in this ordering. It is called the ring of *germs* of polynomials at $\rm\:t = +\infty.$